# In a RealmCollectionChange how do you get the second format?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In the docs for `RealmCollectionChange` it says:

> The change information is available in two formats: a simple array of row indices in the collection for each type of change, and an array of index paths in a requested section suitable for passing directly to `UITableView`'s batch update methods.

All the examples I've seen seem to use the first format, "the simple array of indices".

How do you get that second format, the "array of index paths in a requested section"?

Comment: The first example in the documentation [Register a Collection Change Listener](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/react-to-changes/#register-a-collection-change-listener) shows how to handle deletions, insertions and modifications at an IndexPath. A reminder they must be handled in that order.

Comment: @Jay Thanks. I'm using that example already. In that case the RealmCollectionChange object seems to be providing the "simple array of row indices..." as described in the docs. How does one get the second format "an array of index paths in a requested section"?

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear as we don't know the use case. Take a look at the rest of the documentation which states *For example, for a simple **one-section** table view* which is why the section is set to 0 in that example. Sections and rows are something coded in your app. It's not stored in Realm that way so how would Realm know what row belongs to which section? You have to craft the section and row (IndexPath) based on observing the lower level objects that are changing.

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure the use case matters yet. I'm trying to understand the documentation. It says the change information is available in two formats. At this point I'm just trying to determine if the documentation is correct. And if it's correct, how to get that second format. And if it can be obtained, what cool thing might we be able to accomplish with it. At this point I'm beginning to think an enthusiastic developer wrote that documentation with the sincere intent to implement it that way but in the end it didn't happen.

Comment: The docs have been in that format for years and I agree, it's a bit unclear. The gist of it is that you can be notified of the top level section object changes (and simply reload that section to update the UI) OR the objects within each section which provides a more granular level of control for say, animations.

Comment: Realm has no knowledge of how your Sections and Rows are defined in code which is what's makes up an IndexPath, right? You could query for pizza objects and then another query for pizza restaurants and put the restaurants as rows in the Pizza section - Realm won't know that. However, if you're observing the items that make of up the rows instead of the higher level sections, when an event occurs in a row object, you can get its parent object and craft an IndexPath (row, section). then you have an IndexPath object *suitable for passing directly to UITableView's batch update methods.*

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I was hoping for was behaviour like you get with `NSFetchedResultsController` where you can pass a `sectionNameKeyPath` to the initializer. When you do that, the section-lovin` is handled for you. You get index paths back.